# Do invariant open sets generate the $\sigma$-algebra of invariant sets?

Tags: measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $X$ be a Polish space with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $B(X)$. Let $G$ be a locally compact group. $T:G\times X\to X$ be a continuous action of $G$ on $X$.

The $\sigma$-algebra of invariant sets is defined as $I=\{A\in B(X)\mid T_gA=A,\, \forall g\in G\}$.

We may assume that the metric $d$ of $X$ is invariant under the action of $T_g$ (that is $d(T_gx,T_gy)=d(x,y)$). This in particular implies that every $\delta$-neighbourhood of an invariant set $E$ is itself invariant.

Is it possible to say anything about $I$ being generated by the invariant open sets ? i.e. if $I_{op}=\{ A\in I \mid A\text{ is open}\}$, does
$$
I=\sigma(I_{op})\, ?
$$

Any ideas or reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this false already for an irrational rotation of the circle? There are no nontrivial invariant open sets in this case, but many invariant Borel sets (e.g. every orbit).

Comment: Perhaps one needs to fix the grammar of the title (either add "the family of all..." or make it plural).

Comment: @TobiasFritz You should make an answer out of your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is false already for any [irrational rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_rotation) of the circle, meaning with $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and $X = S^1$:

- Using the fact that every orbit is dense, it is easy to see that the only invariant open sets are the trivial ones ($\emptyset$ and $S^1$ itself).
- On the other hand, there are nontrivial invariant Borel sets, for example every orbit.

More generally, the same idea works whenever every orbit is dense but not all of $X$.

Comment: Probably "surjective" should be "all of $X$" (since I don't think one normally refers to a subset, rather than a map onto it, as surjective).

Comment: Right, that's probably the better way to put it @LSpice. (When I wrote that I was thinking of "orbit" as a map $\mathbb{Z} \to X$, but I agree that considering it as a subset is more coherent here.)